# I need help writing a working ERC 721 contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have been unable to write a working ERC 721 contract.Can someone help me with a sample ERC 721 contract that works? I have been learning for about a week now and I haven't made much progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/41545/33731) helpful.
There are a number of examples available.

E.g.:

- https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC721
- https://github.com/m0t0k1ch1/ERC721-token-sample

Answer (score 2):

A complete reference implementation of the ERC-721 non-fungible token standard for the Ethereum blockchain is available at https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721.

Comment: It's not just *a* reference implementation. It is *the* reference implementation cited in the standard! Don't be modest :-p